# Mocking Azure BlobItem - C# unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, azure-blob-storage

I have some unit tests where I want to mock the Azure `BlobItem` class (Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models).

Here is my test class I'm using. I want the `Values` getter to return a list with a mock BlobItem. That is working.

```
public class TestPage : Page<BlobItem>
{
    public override IReadOnlyList<BlobItem> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<BlobItem>() { new Mock<BlobItem>().Object };
        }
    }

    public override string ContinuationToken => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override Response GetRawResponse()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

However when I do this, the `Name` property on my mock BlobItem is always null.

I can try to set it up so that `Name` would return a mocked value like so:

```
var mock = new Mock<BlobItem>();
mock.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("mock");
```

But then I get an error:

```
Non-overridable members may not be used in setup/verification expressions.
```

I understand why this error is happening. But I do not know what the solution is.

I want a mocked BlobItem to return a non-null `Name` value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Apparently there's a factory class called `BlobsModelFactory`.

You can mock a BlobItem with whatever name you want by calling:

```
var blob = BlobsModelFactory.BlobItem("mocked.mocked.mocked.mocked")
```