# How can I mock Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, azure-blob-storage

I'm rather confused by the `Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient` class.  One of its constructors (without any parameters) has documentation that suggests the class was specifically designed for mocking:

```
// Summary:
//     Initializes a new instance of the Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient class
//     for mocking.
protected BlobContainerClient();
```

However, some of the class's methods require things to be returned that have no public constructor and therefore cannot be meaningfully mocked.  For example:

```
// Summary:
//     The Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient.GetBlobs(Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobTraits,Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobStates,System.String,System.Threading.CancellationToken)
//     operation returns an async sequence of blobs in this container. Enumerating the
//     blobs may make multiple requests to the service while fetching all the values.
//     Blobs are ordered lexicographically by name. For more information, see List Blobs.
//
// Parameters:
//   traits:
//     Specifies trait options for shaping the blobs.
//
//   states:
//     Specifies state options for filtering the blobs.
//
//   prefix:
//     Specifies a string that filters the results to return only blobs whose name begins
//     with the specified prefix.
//
//   cancellationToken:
//     Optional System.Threading.CancellationToken to propagate notifications that the
//     operation should be cancelled.
//
// Returns:
//     An Azure.Pageable`1 of Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobItem describing the blobs
//     in the container.
//
// Remarks:
//     A Azure.RequestFailedException will be thrown if a failure occurs.
public virtual Pageable<BlobItem> GetBlobs(BlobTraits traits = BlobTraits.None, BlobStates states = BlobStates.None, string prefix = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

Although `Pageable<T>` can be mocked because it has a protected constructor, the type that it's required to return (`BlobItem`) cannot; there's no public constructor.  The only thing a mock can do is return an empty list, which is not at all useful.  Am I missing something, or or this a significant oversight in one's ability to mock this class?

Comment: See answer here on how to create your own `BlobItem`s: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913034/633098

Comment: So apparently I have to "vote to close" my own question.  Not sure why considering I created it.  But if there are any mode, I'm telling you my question is a dupe.  I voted to close it.  Can't do much more really, can I?