# How to mock Azure blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync()

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-storage, xunit

I have a Azure blob container which I am accessing using below code -

```
       var blobContainerClient = GetBlobContainer(containerName);
            if (blobContainerClient != null)
            {
                // List all blobs in the container
                await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
                {
                    queuedBlobsList.Add(new QueuedBlobs { BlobName = blobItem.Name, LastModified = blobItem.Properties.LastModified });
                }
            }

    private BlobContainerClient GetBlobContainer(string containerName)
    {
        return gen2StorageClient != null
            ? gen2StorageClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName)
            : gen1StorageClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    }
```

The clients are initialised in constructor -
public class BlobService : IBlobService
{
private readonly BlobServiceClient gen1StorageClient, gen2StorageClient;

```
   public BlobService(BlobServiceClient defaultClient, IAzureClientFactory<BlobServiceClient> clientFactory)
        {
              gen1StorageClient = defaultClient;
              if (clientFactory != null)
              {
               gen2StorageClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("StorageConnectionString");
              }
       }
    }
```

And my unit test where I am setting GetBlobsAsync is like this -
But I want to add list of BlobItems to test another loop.

```
    private static Mock<BlobContainerClient> GetBlobContainerClientMockWithListOfBlobs()
    {
        var blobContainerClientMock = new Mock<BlobContainerClient>("UseDevelopmentStorage=true", EnvironmentConstants.ParallelUploadContainer);
        var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        var blobs = new List<BlobItem>();

        //AsyncPageable<BlobItem> blobItems = new AsyncPageable<BlobItem>(); -- Not allowing
        blobContainerClientMock.Setup(x => x.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.All, BlobStates.All, null, cancellationToken)).Returns(It.IsAny<AsyncPageable<BlobItem>>());
        return blobContainerClientMock;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I came to this question because I also had the same issue.

Based on this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/unit-testing-and-mocking/)

> `AsyncPageable<T>` and `Pageable<T>` are classes that represent collections of models returned by the service in pages.

The method **GetBlobsAsync** returns an AsyncPageable.

To Create an AsyncPageable you need first to create a BlobItem Page.

To create a `Page<T>` instance, use the `Page<T>.FromValues` method, passing a **list of items**, a continuation token, and the Response.

So let's start creating the list of items:

```
var blobList = new BlobItem[]
{
    BlobsModelFactory.BlobItem("Blob1"),
    BlobsModelFactory.BlobItem("Blob2"),
    BlobsModelFactory.BlobItem("Blob3")
};
```

Note: BlobItem has an internal constructor but I found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913034/2437115) that there's a BlobsModelFactory.

After having the list of blobs is time to create a `Page<BlobItem>`:

```
Page<BlobItem> page = Page<BlobItem>.FromValues(blobList, null, Mock.Of<Response>());
```

And finally, create the `AsyncPageable<BlobItem>`

```
AsyncPageable<BlobItem> pageableBlobList = AsyncPageable<BlobItem>.FromPages(new[] { page });
```

And now you are able to use this to mock GetBlobsAsync method:

```
blobContainerClientMock
    .Setup(m => m.GetBlobsAsync(
        It.IsAny<BlobTraits>(),
        It.IsAny<BlobStates>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Returns(pageableBlobList);
```

I hope this helps others with this issue.

André